# CodeIgniter: How to call google places API inside the <head> tag of my site?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project but as a beginner in php programming i have hard times trying to call this library inside the  tag of my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&amp;language=en"></script>
```

I tried to add it in the header.php file of my theme views folder but firebug gives the error message that site cant load the external library !

Where i have to insert this line of code to work properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```